# Npm install not being able to find a file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, homestead

I cloned a git repository, but npm install doesn't work. It is not being able to find a file in @vue folder, which is missing from the folder project.
I am in the project folder when I use npm install.

I tried "npm init", tried to erase the node_modules folder, tried to update npm. And this happens with all projects I create with composer, and with the projects, I clone with GitHub.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Proyectos/test$ npm install
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/Proyectos/test/node_modules/@vue/component-compiler-utils/node_modules/source-map/package.json.3794421909
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/Proyectos/test/node_modules/@vue/component-compiler-utils/node_modules/source-map/package.json.3794421909'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-05-30T04_58_47_485Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you in the same directory as the package.json? that is where you should be running `npm install` if you do have a node_modules delete it and try running npm install.

Comment: Could you show me content of the logs which located in /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-05-30T04_58_47_485Z-debug.log